# Is there a discrepancy between reported and actual SampleRate in AudioGenerator

Tags: bugs, sound, signal-processing

When AudioGenerator is used to generate an Audio object, there may be a discrepancy between the specified (and reported) SampleRate and the actual time difference between the samples. This was observed while using the "Sin" generator, but easier to see using a generator function that returns the time value:

```
aud = AudioGenerator[Identity, 1/100, SampleRate -> 1000];
1./AudioSampleRate[aud]

(* Quantity[0.001, 1/("Hertz")] *)

First@AudioData@aud

(*  {0., 0.00111111, 0.00222222, 0.00333333, 0.00444444, 
       0.00555556, 0.00666667, 0.00777778, 0.00888889, 0.01} *)
```

This looks like an off-by-one error, so is probably not noticeable for long Audio objects, but obviously shifts short Audio objects to a lower frequency.

This has been reported to Wolfram support; I will update this post upon reply.

Version 11.2, macOS High Sierra

**Update:** Problem reproduced by Wolfram support, CASE:3969907.

**Update:** Fixed in 11.3

Comment: You still need to put a *question* in there somewhere, since this is a Q&A site...

Comment: I prefer to think of is as a site to go to to find an answer to a question, whether or not it is phrased as a question. However, I rephrased the question.

Comment: Behavior confirmed by Wolfram support, forwarded to developers. CASE:3969907. Does this mean I can put a "bugs" tag on this?

Comment: I've put it in for you, but yes, you can do so upon confirmation. You might want to edit your question to mention that case number.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in 11.3

```
aud = AudioGenerator[Identity, 1/100, SampleRate -> 1000];
1./AudioSampleRate[aud]

(* Out[ ]= Quantity[0.001, 1/("Hertz")] *)

First@AudioData@aud

(* Out[ ]= {0., 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009}
```